# should i mount a tv on top of gas logs fireplace

Tags: fireplace

Is it okay to put a tv on top of a gas logs fireplace? I am concerned since the emitted gases must be making the walls hot?

Comment: Is there a circulation fan on the gas fireplace that blows the warm air into the room?

Comment: There is none. This is gas logs fireplace. I don't believe it has fans. I haven't started it even once after buying the house last year since I haven't installed a proper switch. Right now the only way to start is using a knob and a lighter.

Answer (score 1):

I say no.  THat TV is full of PC boards.  Printed circuitry hates heat.  Good quality computers have a half dozen cooling fans.